# How can I print only certain fields in a space separated file?

Tags: perl, split, field

I have a file containing the following content 1000 line in the following format:

```
abc def ghi gkl
```

How can I write a Perl script to print only the first and the third fields?

```
abc ghi
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If no answer is good for you yet, I'll try to get the bounty ;-)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# Lines beginning with a hash (#) denote optional comments,
# except the first line, which is required,
# see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

use strict;   # http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html 
use warnings; # http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html

# http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Compound-Statements
# http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html
# http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html
# http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html
# http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators
while (defined(my $line = <>)) {
    # http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html
    my @chunks = split ' ', $line;
    # http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html
    # http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators
    print "$chunks[0] $chunks[2]\n";
}
```

To run this script, given that its name is `script.pl`, invoke it as

```
perl script.pl FILE
```

where `FILE` is the file that you want to parse. See also http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html. Good luck! ;-)

Comment: might even be interesting to replace `split ' '` by `split /\s+/` to split on all sort of spaces (repeated or not)

Comment: @Aif Splitting by `' '` has a special meaning in Perl.

Comment: what is that meaning?

Comment: @Aif, if I'm reading https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html correctly, it enables `awk` emulation: "split emulates the default behavior of the command line tool awk when the PATTERN is either omitted or a string composed of a single space character (such as `' '` or `"\x20"` , but not e.g. `/ /` ). In this case, any leading whitespace in EXPR is removed before splitting occurs, and the PATTERN is instead treated as if it were `/\s+/`"

Answer (score 17):

```
perl -lane 'print "@F[0,2]"' file
```

Comment: Using Perl in awk-killer mode - with autosplit.

Comment: -a implicitly sets -n so you don't need n actually. So perl -lae is enough. But anyway the best answer here

Comment: Just `-lae` not work for Perl v5.18.4. `-n` is needed.

Answer (score 13):

That's really kind of a waste for something as powerful as perl, since you can do the same thing in one trivial line of awk.

`awk '{ print $1 $3 }'`

Comment: @codeholic, if OP *knew* Perl, they wouldn't be asking the question. Using Perl for this is like using a thermonuclear warhead to try and kill a fly. +1 for this answer.

Comment: Doesn't say the platform, but it's easier to get perl than awk for Windows.  Also, this could be part of a larger programming task ... I'm sure awk is up to it, but sometimes the job wants what it wants.

Comment: @Zac: They both require a download and install. awk is part of mingw; download URL is http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/ . I don't do development work on any Windows PC without downloading mingw onto it. Perl OTOH, I only install when I need it

Answer (score 9):

```
while ( <> ) {
    my @fields = split;
    print "@fields[0,2]\n";
}
```

and just for variety, on Windows:

```
C:\Temp> perl -pale "$_=qq{@F[0,2]}"
```

and on Unix

```
$ perl -pale '$_="@F[0,2]"'
```

Answer (score 4):

As perl one-liner:

`perl -ane 'print "@F[0,2]\n"' file`

Or as executable script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'file' or die "Can't open file: $!\n";

while (<$fh>) {
    my @fields = split;
    print "@fields[0,2]\n";
}
```

Execute the script like this:

```
perl script.pl
```

or

```
chmod 755 script.pl  
./script.pl
```

Comment: If you're using strict and warning, you may want to close your file at the end of your script :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure I shouldn't get the bounty since the question asks for the result to be given in perl, but anyway:

In bash/ksh/ash/etc:

```
cut -d " " -f 1,3 "file"
```

In Windows/DOS:

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims= " %i in (file) do (echo %i %k)
```

Advantages: like others said, no need to learn Pearl, Awk, nothing, just knowing some tools. The result of both calls can be saved to the disk by using the ">" and the ">>" operator.

Comment: +1 for cut.  Though cut takes an optional file argument, so I'd probably bypass the cat and the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(<>){
  chomp;
  @s = split ;
  print "$s[0] $s[2]\n";
}
```

please start to go through the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/) as well

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html : A split on `/\s+/`  is like a `split(' ')`  except that any leading whitespace produces a null first field. A split  with no arguments really does a `split(' ', $_)`  internally.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
open my$F, "<", "file" or die;
print join(" ",(split)[0,2])."\n" while(<$F>);
close $F
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is:

```
(split)[0,2]
```

Example:

```
$_ = 'abc def ghi gkl';
print( (split)[0,2] , "\n");
print( join(" ", (split)[0,2]  ),"\n");
```

Command line:

```
perl -e '$_="abc def ghi gkl";print(join(" ",(split)[0,2]),"\n")'
```

Comment: I was confused about the [] construct, had to go on #perl and ask. It's "slice": https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices .